# how to set a return variable in an ajax call in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am working on a photo sharing app in rails using cloudinary gem.
in my #picasController i have the following relevant actions

```
def filter  
    @pica = Pica.find(params[:id])  
    @new_upload = current_user.picas.first  
    effect_id = params[:effect_id]  
    @effect = effect_id.to_sym  
    respond_to do |format|  
         format.html { render 'filter' }  
         format.js  
   end  
  end    

  def share  
    @pica = Pica.find(params[:id])  
    @edited_photo_url = params[:edited_photo]  

    @new_photo_public_id = get_new_public_id(@edited_photo_url)  
    @pica.update_attributes(photo: @new_photo_public_id, user_id: current_user)  
    flash.now[:success] = "Saving Photo: Successful"  
    @new_pica = current_user.picas.first  

  end  

  def edit  
    @pica = Pica.find(params[:id])  
@new_upload = current_user.picas.first  
  end  


//views/edit.html.erb  
<% render 'shared/filter' %>  

  //partial  
   /shared/_filter.html.erb   

     <h2>Select an effect to apply below:</h2>  
      <div id="image-display">  

        <%= cl_image_tag(@new_upload.photo_url(@effect)) %>  
        <% active_effect = :large %>  

      </div>  

       <%= link_to "Remove", @pica, class: "btn btn-warning btn-small", method: :delete,data: { confirm: "Are You sure?" } %><br/>    

    </div>  

    <div class="span2 share-photo-btn"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>    


        <%= active_effect %>    
    <% edited = @new_upload.photo_url(active_effect) %>    
     <%= edited %>    
      <%= link_to "Save and Share", {:controller => :picas, :action => :share, :edited_photo => edited, id: @pica.id}, class: "btn btn-info btn-large" %><br/>    

</div>  

  </div><br/>  
    <div class="effects">  
    <ul class="thumbnails filters">  
    <li>  
    <span class="E_title">Sepia</span>  
    <% thumb_id = "sepia" %>  
  <%= link_to image_tag(@new_upload.photo_url(:sepia)), {:controller => :picas, :action => :filter, id: @pica.id, effect_id: thumb_id}, :data => {:remote=> true},  class: "thumbnail", id: "sepia" %>  
    </li>    

    <li>    
    <span class="E_title">Grayscale</span>  
        <% thumb_id = "grayscale" %>  
  <%= link_to image_tag(@new_upload.photo_url(:grayscale)),    {:controller => :picas, :action => :filter, id: @pica.id, effect_id: thumb_id}, :data => {:remote=> true}, class: "thumbnail", id: "grayscale" %>  
      </li>

      <li>  
       <span class="E_title">Blackwhite</span>  
        <% thumb_id = "blackwhite" %>  
        <%= link_to image_tag(@new_upload.photo_url(:blackwhite)),     {:controller => :picas, :action => :filter, id: @pica.id, effect_id: thumb_id}, :data =>   {:remote=> true}, class: "thumbnail", id: "blackwhite" %>  
    </li>    


//filter.js.erb

<% return_effect =  "original" %>    


<% case @effect    
      when :sepia  
            return_effect =  'sepia'    
      when :grayscale    
            return_effect =  'grayscale'    
      when :blackwhite    
            return_effect =  'blackwhite'    
      when :gradient_fade
            return_effect =  'gradient_fade'    
      when :negate
            return_effect =  'negate'      
      when :vignette  
            return_effect =  'vignette'    
         else  
   return_effect  
   end
%>  


//this loads a partial depending on the value of 'return_effect'  
   $("#image-display").html('<%= escape_javascript(render("#{return_effect}")).html_safe %>')
```

please my problem is having the active_effect variable in the filter partial set to the correct value whenever a user clicks on an effect. i've tried including it in the partial being loaded when an effect is clicked but it doesent work like this:

when a user clicks on the sepia effect link:
the partial to be loaded with js is this:

```
 //_sepia.html.erb  
  <%= cl_image_tag(@new_upload.photo_url(:sepia_canvas)) %>  
<% active_effect = :sepia_canvas %>  

  <br/>
```

but still doesn't work.
all i need is for the value of active_effect variable to be updated whenever a link is clicked.
active_effect is still set on the default :large and doesnt update.
please help i have been cracking my head up for days.
i am  ready  to provide additional information if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **asynchronous** tasks, the best practice is not to return any value (if you do, most of the time it returns nothing), instead, if you want to manipulate any data (from async response), pass a **callback**, handle the data inside the callback.

Don't:

```
def async_task
  do_sth
  return response
end
```

Do:

```
def async_task(&blk)
  do_sth
  blk.call(response)
end
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply.. i'm actually kinda new to ajax on rails.. can you suggest any pointers on how to use a callback to do such in rails? thanks

Comment: No problem.  And I just edited my answer to have some pseudo code examples.  Hope you get an idea from them.